# Display all data in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

i need to display data like : {"Ram":"1GB","Color":"BLACK"}
if i use :

```
alert(main.newProduct.Specification =  ("{\""+main.specifications[0].key+"\":\""+main.specifications[0].value+"\",\""+main.specifications[1].key+"\":\""+main.specifications[1].value+"\"}"));
```

it will be ok, but if i change to this

```
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<main.specifications.length;i++){
        alert(main.newProduct.Specification =  ("{\""+main.specifications[i].key+"\":\""+main.specifications[i].value+"\"}"));
    }
```

it show one by one. i want to show all just one alert , can it?
sorry, i am new for js.

Comment: prepare alert message value in loop then display a single `alert`.

Comment: where do you get `main.specifications` from? you iterating al characters, if the value is a string, as i suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
JSON.stringify( main.specification )
```

Comment: its look nice , all stored inside , but it should be customized . cheers @helloheffhall

Comment: Cheers! What kind of customization did you have in mind? If you want the data to look a little nicer you can pass a parameter to add spacing like `JSON.stringify( main.specification, null, 2 )`

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to simply join:

```
var string="{"+main.specifications.map({key,value}=>key+":"+value).join()+"}";
```

And then you can either alert:

```
alert(string);
```

or show it on the page:

```
document.body.innerHTML=string;
```

or add it to your new product:

```
newProduct.specification=string;
```

Comment: alert only for testing , i want to set main.newProduct.Specification with the value of array . but if i use for loop , its only fill the last array .. how can?